# How to fix error (unresolved reference: editText issue ) in android?

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin

The `kotlin-android-extensions` Gradle plugin is deprecated. Please use [this migration guide](https://goo.gle/kotlin-android-extensions-deprecation) to start working with [View Binding](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/view-binding) and the `kotlin-parcelize` plugin.

```
C:\\Users\\ADMINISTRATOR\\AndroidStudioProjects\\MyApplication4\\app\\src
\\main\\java\\com\\denizas\\myapplication\\MainActivity.kt: (14, 21):
Unresolved reference: editText

Caused by: org.gradle.api.GradleException:
Compilation error. See log for more details
```

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/251916/discussion-on-question-by-gencay-deniz-unresolved-reference-edittext-issue); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> build.gradle(Module:App)

```
android {
....
buildFeatures {
            viewBinding true
        }
}
```

> MainActivity.kt

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

private var _binding: ActivityMainBinding? = null
    private val binding
        get() = _binding!!

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) { 
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
_binding = ActivityChartBinding.inflate(layoutInflater) 
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main) 
} 
fun topla(view: View){
binding.apply {
//in this part it is used to access the views in the layout part
       var sayi1 = editText.text.toStirng()
      }
  } 
}
```

Comment: class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    private var _binding: ActivityMainBinding? = null
    private val binding
        get() = _binding!!

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        _binding = ActivityChartBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)//"ActivityChartBinding" burası kırmızı
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
    }
    fun topla(view: View){
        binding.apply {
            var sayi1 = editText.text.toStirng()//"editText" hala kırmızı

Comment: dc den beni ekler misin

Comment: sana linkedin üzerinden attım